# Is it bad to have 3 levels of divs on the z-axis

Tags: html, css

As a general rule of design is it looked down upon to have more than one div ontop of the page contents?  I have a table with records and a div that sits ontop of the table which moves to the vertical position of that record which contains sub-records upon the click. These sub-records in the div also have a level of sub-records themselves and I wish to put another div ontop of the first displaying info about them. Would that be too ridiculous?

Comment: Although an answer has been accepted, it might be worth asking questions like this on the [UX StackExchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely up to you, it depends on your requirements.  As long as the design works for you and you are happy with the way it functions.  There is no specific reason that this should be discouraged unless of course it makes the UI messy really.

Comment: Ok thanks, I am just trying to cut down on the number of pages that must be visited while increasing functionality.

Comment: Yeah I mean you can have as many divs as you like layered ontop of each other.  Theres no reason (that I know of) why you shouldnt be doing this.  If they are the same colour etc though it can get a bit confusing as to where the upper one finishes and the lower one starts, so using borders, drop shaddows etc can help to define the area over which the divs cover.

Comment: Cool and yeah I didnt really either but I will keep those options in mind